# Why my fadeToggle dosen't apply to the red box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click the button it support to fade in and out the red button, but it doesn't so what is the problem ?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  ${"button").click(function(){
  $("div").fadeToggle();
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <button>Click Here To FadeToggle</button><br><br>
 <div style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a type error  `${` should be `$(`

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
${"button")
 ^---------------
```

**To:**

```
$("button")
 ^---------------
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("div").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Here To FadeToggle</button><br><br>
<div style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```